# Updating a table depending on some conditions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

There is table called `payment_history`.

```
payment_history
  id
  status_name
  added_at
  user_id
```

There are 3 statuses: `paid, pre_active` and `active`. There can be only one item with the status "`active`" for a given user. For simplicity suppose that the field status is of type `varchar` (`status_name`), not `integer` (it would be `status_id` then). I want to find out whether or not a particular user (`user_id`) has status active.

**a) If the user doesn't:**

a1) If at least one row with the status "`pre_active`" exist (there can be many of them), find the most oldest one (by `added_at`) and make it "`active`"

a2) If not then find the rows with the status "`paid`", make all of them "`pre_active`" and, again, find the most oldest one (by `added_at`) and make it "`active`"

**b) If the user does (have the status "`active`"):**

b1) just `raise` a notice saying this.

Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_payment_history(user_id integer)
  RETURNS SETOF void AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

  --1 
  -- if there is no active status
  IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM payment_history WHERE status_name = 'active' and user_id = $1
  ) THEN
    -- if pre_active exists then select the oldest one and make it active  
    IF EXISTS (
      SELECT id FROM payment_history WHERE status_name = 'pre_active' and user_id = $1
    ) THEN

      -- todo make a function to get rid of the repetition?
      UPDATE payment_history
      SET status_name = 'active'
      WHERE p.user_id = $1
      AND status_name = 'pre_active'
      ORDER BY added_at DESC LIMIT 1;

    ELSE
      UPDATE payment_history
      SET status_name = 'pre_active'
      WHERE p.user_id = $1
      AND status_name = 'paid';

      -- todo make a function to get rid of the repetition?
      UPDATE payment_history
      SET status_name = 'active'
      WHERE p.user_id = $1
      AND status_name = 'pre_active'
      ORDER BY added_at DESC LIMIT 1;

    END; 

  ELSE
    RAISE NOTICE 'the user has the status active'
    RETURN;
  END IF;

END;
$BODY$
```

First of all, I guess there may be a simpler way to achieving this as there is too much code repetition in here. 
Secondly, I guess `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` functions can be replaced with something similar that fits better (just my guess).

Your thoughts?

Comment: Don't use `IF`, put the condition in the `WHERE` clause. It works even if no rows match the condition.